# Permutations with indistinguishable objects vs Distinguishable objects and distinguishable boxes.

Tags: combinatorics, balls-in-bins

When we consider permutation with indistinguishable objects (I assume without repetiton), the formula for the total number of permuations is:

$\frac{n!}{n_1!n_2!...n_k!}$.

(The number of different permutations of n objects, where there are
n_1 indistinguishable objects of type 1, n_2 indistinguishable objects of type 2, …., and n_k indistinguishable objects of type k, is:)

For  Distinguishable objects and distinguishable boxes we have:

$\frac{n!}{n_1!n_2!...n_k!}$.

(distributing n distinguishable objects into k distinguishable boxes.)

How is this possible? In the first case the objects are indistinguishable while in the second Distinguishable. How is it that the case of Distinguishable objects and distinguishable boxes represents permutation with indistinguishable objects (I assume it does, since the formula is the same).

EDIT:

Let's say all the objects (distinguishable ) are put in the same box (distinguishable ). How is this translated to a permutation??

Comment: You need to provide more context here. Please edit to tell us what the numbers $n_1,\dots,n_k$ refer to, in the context of both problems. This is very important; small changes in the wording of a combinatorics question make huge changes in the count.

Comment: I fixed it. Though I don't see the point of getting a negative mark, just for not being precise. You ain't allowed to formulate something wrong here?

Comment: I don't follow.  There is only one way to place all the objects in one box unless we care about how they are arranged within the box.  Moreover, there are $k^n$ ways to place $n$ distinct objects into $k$ distinct boxes since we have $k$ choices for each object.

Comment: So you are assuming repetition ? since $k^n$. Basically there is a set  that has k distinguishable elements. And you choose n time from it.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig one follow up question: Would it be ok to say that distinguishable objects= use of permutation, indistinguishable objects= use of combination? Or, it's more of a case by case thing?

Comment: You still have not said what $n_1,\dots,n_k$ mean in the context of the second problem. When you answer this, it will be clear why putting all of the objects in the first box is not a valid option (except when only $n_1$ is nonzero).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first part where you are talking of "indistinguishable" objects, the objects are not really indistinguishable, as they are divided into distinguishable **types.**

In fact, both the (identical) formulas you have written are simply the **multinomial coefficient**, which has various interpretations.

- distinct objects into distinct boxes with $n_1$ in box $1$ (not $n_1$ in **any box**), $n_2$ in box $2$, $n_3$ in box $3$ etc
- dividing people into teams, with the people getting labeled according to the team they are put in
- permutations of distinct objects where some elements are repeated

The formulas for all three are equivalent, viz
$$\binom{10}{2,3,3,2} \equiv \binom{10}2\binom83\binom53\binom22 \equiv \frac{10!}{2!3!3!2!}$$

The multinomial coefficient does **not** give all ways of dividing distinct objects into distinct boxes, eg for the simple case with $3$ distinct objects and $2$ boxes,

$\large\binom{3}{3,0} = 1,\;\;  \binom{3}{2,1} = 3,\;\;  \binom{3}{1,2} = 3,\;\;  \binom{3}{0,3} = 1$

Total arrangements $=8 = 2^3$, as it should be

Comment: For the 3rd case, permutation of distinguishable objects with repetition, the formula is $n^r$, for a set of n elements, and we pick r times? How is this the multinomial coef. ?

Comment: @imbAF: "permutation of distinguishable objects where *some elements are repeated*" e.g. permutations of  MISSISSIPPI

Comment: so indistinguishable then. Because in "MISSISIPPI" you have for example 3 Ss, which represent indistinguishable elements. Unless I am mistaken

Comment: @imbAF: The emphasis is on **some** elements repeated/identical/indistinguishable.

Answer (score 0):

A concrete example might help to establish the connection between the two.

Suppose we have 15 distinguishable objects, numbered $1$ to $15$, and four distinguishable boxes, labeled $\text{A,B,C,D}$. Box $\text{A}$ should get 4 objects, box $\text{B}$ should get 3, box $\text{C}$ should get 6 and box $\text{D}$ should get 2.

One way to distribute the objects among the boxes is simply to list all 15 numbers in order and then under each place the letter of the box that object is going into. For example,

$$\begin{array}{c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c}
1 &2 &3 &4 &5 &6 &7 &8 &9 &10 &11 &12 &13 &14 &15 \\
\text{C} &\text{A} &\text{A} &\text{B} &\text{C} &\text{B} &\text{A} &\text{C} &\text{C} &\text{D} &\text{A} &\text{C} &\text{D} &\text{B} &\text{C} 
\end{array}$$

But then clearly there is a 1-to-1 correspondence between the number of ways of distributing the 15 objects to the 4 boxes and the number of permutations of that 15-string of 4 letters.